# Append to txt (plain text)

Tags: notes

## Problem

I want to append to a txt-file from my android. Just like [Drafts](http://agiletortoise.com/drafts/) does would be nice, ie:

1. Open the app
2. Type
3. Hit a button
4. Choose what to do (this is where Drafts shine; I can choose to email somebody, append to a txt, google it, create an event in my calendar, etc)
5. Close the app

The point is: I want creation to be *fast* and not have to hit a lot of buttons.

## Possible solutions

**1) Dropsync**

Storing a file on my SD-card, and having it synced with [Dropsync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync&hl=sv) is an alternative, but two problems would occur

- I have to turn on dropsync to sync very often, which is hard when you own a Nexus 7 and not a phone since I don't have wifi everywhere
- frequent syncing would lower battery levels a lot.

**2) Evernote**

Worst case, I could settle upon append to a note in evernote.

Comment: Looks like a job for *Tasker*, but might not that easy to set up. You can append text to a file with it, and there are at least 3 addons tor Dropbox communication; so you could trigger the sync to take place right before typing and a second time after appending. Just a raw idea; I didn't create such a setup, hence no full-fledged answer.

Comment: Why do you have to "turn on dropsync to sync very often"? That's not stated as part of your problem. Do you need to sync your file or not.

Comment: it is a problem because I don't have 3G internet access everywhere - the sync would fail.